# When assigning a PHP.ini Firefox 3.6x is not displaying a response page when there is a php exception

Tags: php, firefox, iis-7, windows-7, notifications

I hope I can be brief and still allow you to understand the actual problem.
Here goes:

```
[Environment]
Windows 7 Premium 64bit
IIS 7.0
PHP 5.3.3 VC9 Nonthread safe ZIP
mysql 5

[Description of the Problem]
Installed PHP to C:\PHP
```

When no defined "PHP.ini" is set in the C:\PHP folder, Firefox / IE, is able to load PHP files and display PHP exceptions fine.

this is displayed when view phpinfo();

```
Configuration File (php.ini)
Path       C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File       (none)
```

When I modified the PHP.ini-development to PHP.ini -- this is where the problem is.
IE 7, 8 displays PHP exceptions just fine
Firefox displays PHP pages, but not the exceptions... Where there is an exceptions, it just displays blank page or does not load the page at all.
it just looks like the browser is refreshing.

this is what phpinfo(); displays:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path       C:\Windows
Loaded Configuration File       C:\PHP\php.ini
```

So to reiterate, with PHP.ini loaded, Firefox is not displaying any errors generated by PHP (exceptions and not user generated errors)

I've googled and only found one post about this with no solution or any leads to go on.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox-3.0/+bug/244432

attached is my php.ini file if that matters
as well as IE8 screen and FF screen. (FF screen is blank which is the problem)

[sorry can't post links since i am new]

thanks in advance.

[update 11/30 @ 19:31 ET]
@Viper_SB, you're correct. After taking your suggestion of download HTTP headers, the following is captured:

GET /admin/phperror.php HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:801
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12 FirePHP/0.5
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
x-insight: activate

HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Wed, 01 Dec 2010 00:33:36 GMT
Content-Length: 129

But still, nothing is displayed:

Comment: what type of exception is triggered? have you looked at your error log?

Comment: -1 Not a programming problem; belongs on serverfault, if at all. Just install XAMPP or something.

Comment: error log doesnt trigger when FF is used to browse the page generating the error. error log is trigged when IE is used to browse the page.

Comment: @mario. It's likely other developers on SO would have come across the issue. I don't think it deserves a -1.

Comment: @rick. try with a bare minimum firefox with no add-on or plugin (maybe download portable firefox - http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/firefox_portable) and try with it. if you see the error, it's likely an add-on or plugin you have installed it causing the error.

Comment: i thought so too, but i went to another computer - MAC, and tried to do it with the FF i have there... same results. but let me try the portable one.

Comment: @ben. i think you've pointed me one step closer. I was able to see the error message in the portable browser. now i need to figure out what may be causing it on the standard FF. THANKS!

Comment: @Ben, i've disabled all add-ons and plugins still no luck. is the portable browser indeed a replica of firefox? in any case, should my next step be uninstalling firefox completely and reinstalling?

Comment: @Rick. You can try, but you'll need to delete all your settings.. ... or maybe just do your dev work with FF portable

Comment: @Rick yes try a clean profile, if that doesn't work make sure you do not have any toolbars installed, I know you said you disabled add ons but some toolbars are not considered addons (or at least not disable-able from add ons)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume here that you DO have error_reporting enabled and setup correctly in php.ini.

Do you have the FF extension Live HTTP headers? If not install it and open the window, then run the page that doesn't work. Check the headers does it say:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
```

If so your browser (or some other application) could be hiding the real the problem because it's saying it's an error. A lot of times browsers will try to display a friendly error to you if there is a 500 error (or 404 etc...)

The new AVG toolbar WILL cause this problem, but it'd do it in IE and in FF.

Comment: The type exception doesnt matter. Any exception is causing FF to show-up as blank. I will check what type of header it is sending back, but it doesnt seem like it is sending back anything.

Comment: Note: this is only happening to FF. IE is showing the PHP exceptions just fine. but I do not want to limit myself to just using IE for development. I would like to resolve this and more importantly understand why this is happening to FF. if i delete the PHP.ini file from c:\PHP, FF works and displays errors just fine again.

Comment: @Rick Check the HTTP error code, by default a 500 server error is thrown for ANY error triggered from PHP (or exception). Normally a browser will just show it.

Comment: @viper, i understand that each page response has a corresponding header and code... but the peculiar thing is that with FF, the page with the KNOWN error (as seen in IE), it doesnt even load the page... it just refreshes. for example: 1) i goto google.com, the page completes loading 2) i paste the url of the script that would cause the error into the FF address bar 3) the status bar below acts like a refresh, nothing happens, the google page is still displayed.

Comment: what are the chances that this could be a corrupt PHP.ini? Again, if this were happening to IE as well, i would understand, just dont know why it is only happening to FF.

Comment: @Viper_SB, you're correct. i've posted the output by HTTP HEADER per your suggestion in my initial post. see if that helps you identify anything.